# Salesforce- JS path shows null

Tags: javascript, xpath, automated-tests, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I copied the JS patch and pasted it to the console which shows that the item is **null**. It is the same with the other fields.
**What is it, how do get around it** because I have a problem in automatic tests because I get an error that the item is not clickable

[Copy JS path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajFaq.png)  [Copy JS path2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHvoO.png)

[JS path shows null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfhdZ.png)

I noticed that div class = "action Body" is not null and everything else is underneath it.

[Copy JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFJwQ.png)
[JS isn't null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmXQr.png)

Comment: What is "JS Path"? Did you mean "CSS selector"?

Comment: No, it is Java Script Path. I added an additional picture in the description ("Copy JS path2").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce's Lightning Experience UI is pain to use with Selenium etc JS unit tests. The field ids are semi-random.

You could have more luck if it's a custom piece (Lightning Web Component or Aura component), these are testable with Jest for example: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/testing, https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/test-lightning-web-components/write-a-jest-test

But standard pages like "new Account" - you'll have hard time. Also because SF uses [shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) (native where possible, polyfilled for IE11 etc). The page you see is not a happy soup of html and css and being able to traverse whole DOM tree. It's a set of components, black boxes that hide their internal workings, that don't have problems when 2 use same function name, that communicate with events instead of writing to another area's raw HTML... So it's hard to write tests on it, it's hard to attach <strike>spyware</strike>... analytics, click tracking etc rubbish.

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/01/ui-test-automation-on-salesforce.html
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/02/how-to-write-stable-selenium-tests-for-lightning-ui.html
https://thereluctanttester.com/2020/08/15/lessons-learnt-from-a-poc-to-automate-salesforce-lightning-ui/

There's company called Provar that claims to have success with testing. Do your own evaluation (or search for "lightning experience automated testing"), I'm not affiliated in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer.

I found the solution: I added one step before clicking to picklist and this helped…
[image: Add step before clicking]

Before:
[image]